# Vaadin with spring boot - logout fails with NPE - VaadinServletResponse is null

Tags: vaadin

This is for Vaadin 24. Our app is derived from Vaain's starter that uses spring-security. The starter uses the navbar with a "Sign Out" button. That button calls logout() on the AuthenticationContext. That throws an NPE because the VaadinServletResponse is null.

Why is the servlet response null?  This is inside Vaadin's framework where we can't override so there is no easy work-around. Its just broken.  We have not modified the Vaadin default servlet.

```
// Vaadin starter app generated this code
public class MainLayout extends AppLayout {
    private Footer createFooter() {
            MenuItem userName = userMenu.addItem( "" );
            userName.getSubMenu().addItem( "Sign out", e -> {
                authenticatedUser.logout();
            } );
    }
}

// our authenticated user class
@Component
public class AuthenticatedUser {

    private UserDAO userDAO;

    private final AuthenticationContext authenticationContext;

    public AuthenticatedUser( AuthenticationContext authenticationContext ) {
        this.authenticationContext = authenticationContext;
        userDAO = new UserDAO();
    }

    public void logout() {
        try {
            authenticationContext.logout();
        }
        catch ( Throwable th ) {
            // NPE happens here: VaadinServletResponse is null
            error( LogMsgParams.of( EXCEPTION_LOG, EXCEPTION_MRKR, "Logout failed.", th ) );
        }
    }
}

// this is Vaadin's implementation
public class AuthenticationContext {

    public void logout() {
        HttpServletRequest request = VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent()
                .getHttpServletRequest();
        HttpServletResponse response = VaadinServletResponse.getCurrent()
                .getHttpServletResponse();

        // other stuff
    }

}
```

Error: VaadinServletResponse.getCurrent() is null.
Exception:

> 2023-03-31_10:29:31.086 ERROR EXCEPTION [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-10] at (com.extrospectre.log.Logging:225) - Logout failed.
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletResponse.getHttpServletResponse()" because the return value of "com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServletResponse.getCurrent()" is null
> at com.vaadin.flow.spring.security.AuthenticationContext.logout(AuthenticationContext.java:123)
> at test.webapp.security.AuthenticatedUser.logout(AuthenticatedUser.java:57)
> at test.webapp.view.MainLayout.lambda$0(MainLayout.java:149)
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.fireEventForListener(ComponentEventBus.java:233)
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.handleDomEvent(ComponentEventBus.java:475)
> at com.vaadin.flow.component.ComponentEventBus.lambda$addDomTrigger$dd1b7957$1(ComponentEventBus.java:292)
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.lambda$fireEvent$2(ElementListenerMap.java:447)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at com.vaadin.flow.internal.nodefeature.ElementListenerMap.fireEvent(ElementListenerMap.java:447)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.EventRpcHandler.handleNode(EventRpcHandler.java:62)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.rpc.AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.handle(AbstractRpcInvocationHandler.java:74)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocationData(ServerRpcHandler.java:438)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.lambda$handleInvocations$1(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:419)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:320)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushHandler.lambda$new$1(PushHandler.java:155)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushHandler.callWithUi(PushHandler.java:264)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushHandler.onMessage(PushHandler.java:591)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler.onMessage(PushAtmosphereHandler.java:90)
> at com.vaadin.flow.server.communication.PushAtmosphereHandler.onRequest(PushAtmosphereHandler.java:79)
> at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:219)
> at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:105)
> at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:67)
> at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2286)
> at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:584)
> at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor$3.run(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:335)
> at org.atmosphere.util.VoidExecutorService.execute(VoidExecutorService.java:101)
> at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:330)
> at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.invokeWebSocketProtocol(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:438)
> at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint$1.onMessage(JSR356Endpoint.java:267)
> at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint$1.onMessage(JSR356Endpoint.java:264)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:415)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.sendMessageText(WsFrameServer.java:129)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:515)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:301)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:85)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:183)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:162)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:157)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:60)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:59)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

```
public class LoginView extends LoginOverlay implements BeforeEnterObserver {

    public LoginView( AuthenticatedUser authenticatedUser ) {
        addLoginListener( event -> {
            System.out.println( "User login: " + event.getUsername() ); // this line is never reached
        }
    }
}
```

That code is not working. The login is not really working which is probably why the logout does not work.  They way over architected this thing! They chose to use Spring Boot -> Spring Security -> Spring Data, and if you try to replace any of that it breaks the whole thing. Its all or nothing. That means the UI has to connect directly to the DB.  Not good!

Comment: What you are trying to do with the request and response at logout? It sounds a bit odd to me. You should just invalidate the session and do nothing more there. And say if the session is invalidated correctly as it should, those thread locals should have been cleared and should return null.

Comment: Vaadin uses spring-security so there is an authentication process with an AuthenticatedUser.  You have to logout that user in spring. That is called through the AuthenticationContext.

Comment: It may be a bug, as it seems the requested is sent to the server through websocket and the PushHandler may not have set the thread local value for VaadinResponse. It would be good to create an issue on vaadin flow repository, providing a reproducible example

Comment: This problem remains unresolved in Vaadin 24.0.5.  There is no way to logout of Vaadin!

Comment: We removed the Spring Security from our app. That was the only way we could fix it. Now we have basic login view tied to our own app sec.